# How to get human readable std::string from RSA_private_encrypt

Tags: c++, openssl

I have RSA encrypted my string but it's now a unsigned char *. How do I create a human readable std::string that I can output for the user? I want to use it in an amazon signed url. Here are the meat and potatoes of the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/RSA_SHA1_Encode_CPP/blob/master/RSA_SHA1_Encode_CPP/main.cpp)

```
unsigned char* RSA_SHA1_Sign(std::string policy, RSA *privateKey) throw(std::runtime_error)
{

    //sha1 digest the data
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {'0'};
    SHA1((const unsigned char *)policy.c_str(), policy.length(), hash);

    // Sign the data
    int rsaSize = RSA_size(privateKey);
//    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> signedData(new unsigned char[size]);//if c++11 available
unsigned char *signedData = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * rsaSize);
    unsigned int signedSize = 0;

    //use RSA_sign instead of RSA_private_encrypt
    if(!RSA_sign(NID_sha1, hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, signedData, &signedSize, privateKey)){
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to sign");
    }

    return signedData;
}

std::string base64Encode(unsigned char *signedData)
{
    //prepare
    BIO *b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO *bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

    //write
    BIO_write(b64, signedData, 256);
    BIO_flush(b64);


    //create string
    BUF_MEM *bptr;
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);
    std::string base64String(bptr->data);

    BIO_free_all(b64);
    return base64String;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    RSA *privateKey = createRSAFromPrivateKeyFile("/path/to/privatekey");
    std::string sourceString = "testing";
    std::string signature = RSA_SHA1_Sign(sourceString, privateKey);
    std::string encodedSignature = base64Encode(signature);
    std::cout << "RESULT: " << encodedSignature << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I was using the wrong sign function. Once updated, using base64 encode gave me the correct string.

> RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
>              PKCS #1 v1.5 padding. This function does not handle the algorithmIdentifier specified in PKCS #1.
>              When generating or verifying PKCS #1 signatures, RSA_sign(3) and RSA_verify(3) should be used.

Comment: Simply use the std::string constructor: std::string( char \*data, int size ) :-) The size will be useful as the output MIGHT contain a *null* character.

Comment: an std::string will happily store completely unreadable data. Consider rewording your question to state whether you specifically need a human-readable string, and if so, what format, or if you just want to spew out the raw key bytes.

Comment: `malloc`? In our moment of C++?

Comment: (malloc) Yeah, I'm just fiddling around trying to get things to work for now.

Comment: Than consider using the base64 encoding (to send it to amazon over an url...), again, as the encrypted data might contain NULLs and other shenanigans

Comment: Are you sure you want to sign a human-readable version of `hash`? That makes very, very little sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't want human readable version of hash. That is the from part. I'm looking to use signedData in an URL.

Comment: @joels If you're not using a human readable version of hash, why are you calling `strlen` on it?

Comment: @Xabre base64 encode was the right answer here. If you create an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save all the data, use this std::string constructor: std::string( char *data, int size ). The size will be useful as the output MIGHT contain a null character.

To send it to amazon over an url, consider using the base64 encoding, again, as the encrypted data might contain NULLs and other shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to get it into an `std::string` object, which will probably be helpful in general:

`std::string s{private_key, size};`

However, to then make that compatible with Amazon's scheme you'll need to pick out (or write your own) Base64 library and URL encoder to escape special URL chars. A cursory search of Google or StackOverflow will provide you with what you need in this respect and it's beyond the scope of this question to write out how to do Base64 encoding and URL escaping in C++.

Also, since you're using C++, consider `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` rather than straight-up `malloc();`

`std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> signedData{new unsigned char[size]};`

Comment: indeed, use *unique_ptr*...if his compiler supports C++11... :-)

Comment: The question specifically asks for a *human-readable* string.

Comment: It didn't when I wrote it. Will adjust in any case

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'm still not getting the expected results. I added a github link to the question.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe there is some padding added and you need to take that fact into account

Comment: Is there some other padding I can add other than RSA_PKCS1_PADDING?